# App has exited with code 1 (0x1), When runnin on local machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-10, uwp

I am developing a Universal windows app and its working fine on Windows Phone, Phone Emulators but when I try to run this on local machine (desktop) it keep exiting with message " App has exited with code 1" which I think someone send an exit signal with 1, but why ...? no info available.

I found some related questions but non of them have definite answer.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

App.xaml.cs code

```
 public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ExtendedSplashScreenFactory = (splashscreen) => new ExtendedSplashScreen(splashscreen);

#if DEBUG
            HockeyClient.Current.Configure("Appid");
            HockeyClient.Current.SendCrashesAsync();
#endif
            // start live tiles updates
            SportsClassLibrary.Common.SportsLiveTiles.StartPeriodicTileUpdate("https://tve.rpc.org/windows/sportsTile.cgi");

        }

        protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            _container.RegisterType<IAlertDialogService, AlertDialogService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            _container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            _container.RegisterType<IConfigService, ConfigServices>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            _container.RegisterInstance <INavigationService>(this.NavigationService);
            _container.RegisterInstance<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
            ServiceLocator.SetUnityContainer(_container);

            // override the default viewmodel assembly location
            Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) =>
            {
                var viewModelTypeName = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SportClassLibrary.ViewModels.{0}ViewModel,SportClassLibrary", viewType.Name);
                var viewModelType = Type.GetType(viewModelTypeName);
                return viewModelType;
            });

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
        protected override object Resolve(Type type)
        {
            return _container.Resolve(type);
        }
        protected override async Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                IConfigService configServices = (IConfigService)ServiceLocator.getServiceInstanceForType(typeof(IConfigService));
                await configServices.GetConfigAsync();
            }

            this.NavigationService.Navigate(Experiences.Experience.Epg.ToString(), null);
        }
    }
```

All methods execute fine

Comment: have you thought to use the debugger and step through the code on the local machine..? also how can you expect anyone to help  you without showing code ..this could be any number of errors and or reasons why the error is happening.. show your code that you are running on the local machine

Comment: Yes I debug and step through but its not crashing on specific line, all methods executing fine and then suddenly app quits with this message.

Comment: I have added some App.xaml.cs code, but that work fine, thing which make me more worried why its running fine on some desktops and on all Mobiles devices and emulators.

Comment: not to sound rude.. but this is the classic case of `it works fine on my machine` type of scenario.. perhaps there are dll version issues on other machines.. .net framework version issues etc.. this sounds like you will have to track down all commonalities as well as what's missing on the other machines.. I would add some logging so that you can track and or trace down what's happening

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I found the issue, that was I was sending crash report to hockey asynchronously in constructor method, moving that out fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the issue, actually I was sending crash report to hockey asynchronously in constructor method, `HockeyClient.Current.SendCrashesAsync();` moving this code to `OnInitializeAsync` method fix this issue.